# How to deploy a war in a jetty embedded server running into an executable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jetty, war

I want to deploy a war file, let's call it app.war, onto an embedded jetty.

So the simpliest code for that is:

```
new WebAppContext(server, path, "/");
```

where path is eventually something like "./dist/app.war". And it works like a charm when running from Eclipse, but things get worse when I want to do the same thing from a runnable jar of my project.

Even if the jar architecture is good :

- META-INF
- dist

  - app.war
- ...

The file is not found. I know standard paths are not consistent in running jar files but trying with "jar:file:.../project.jar!/dist/app.jar" doen't do better. Is there any solution for this issue ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

i will use uber plugin to make executable jar. with maven you can simply add

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>uber-${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

check here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
this will create fully self-contained jar with all resources, classes and dependencies